# Assigning values to global environment variable using parallel sapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, environment

I have recently started working with the `parallel` package in R and it is working wonders for me. Still, I have encountered an issue for which I have not found answer.

I am trying to reformat some data and, to do so, I use `sapply()` or `parSapply()` in the parallel case. In the normal case, I go:

```
sapply(1:nrow(aux),function(x){
  r=which(M$Project==aux$Projecte[x] & M$Product==aux$Producte[x])
  c=which(names(M)==aux$Atribut[x])
  l=aux$meanss[x]
  M[r,c]<<-l
})
```

Using `<<-` to assign value to global environment. For the parallel case, I go:

```
no_cores <- detectCores()-2
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl,c("aux","M"))
parSapply(cl,1:20,function(x){
  r=which(M$Project==aux$Projecte[x] & M$Product==aux$Producte[x])
  c=which(names(M)==aux$Atribut[x])
  l=aux$meanss[x]
  M[r,c]<<-l
})
```

I know that the values are being computed (they are printed) but they are not assigned to the `M` dataframe the same way as with `sapply()`. I have looked around but haven't found any information regarding this. Is there any special consideration which I should consider to assign values inside parallel apply functions?
Thank you and please find a reproducible example below.

**M:**

```
structure(list(Project = c("11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", 
"11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", 
"11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119"
), Product = c("Brulerie St. Denis (BOLD)", "Ethical Beans (BOLD)", 
"Folgers (BOLD)", "Illy drip coffe (BOLD)", "Illy Espresso Coffee (BOLD)", 
"Just Us (BOLD)", "Lavazza caffè espresso (BOLD)", "Lavazza Crema e gusto (BOLD)", 
"Lavazza Tierra (BOLD)", "Medaglia d'Oro (BOLD)", "Seattle Best 4 (BOLD)", 
"Starbucks café Verona (BOLD)", "Tully's (BOLD)"), Thing1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Thing2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

**aux:**

```
structure(list(Projecte = c("11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", 
"11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", 
"11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", "11I040119", 
"11I040119", "11I040119"), Producte = c("Brulerie St. Denis (BOLD)", 
"Ethical Beans (BOLD)", "Folgers (BOLD)", "Illy drip coffe (BOLD)", 
"Illy Espresso Coffee (BOLD)", "Just Us (BOLD)", "Lavazza caffè espresso (BOLD)", 
"Lavazza Crema e gusto (BOLD)", "Lavazza Tierra (BOLD)", "Medaglia d'Oro (BOLD)", 
"Seattle Best 4 (BOLD)", "Starbucks café Verona (BOLD)", "Tully's (BOLD)", 
"Brulerie St. Denis (BOLD)", "Ethical Beans (BOLD)"), Thing = c("Thing1", 
"Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", 
"Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing2"
), Value = c(0.142857142857143, 0.242857141154153, 0.614285715988704, 
0, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 1.01428570917674, 0, 0.971428564616612, 
0.5, 0.357142857142857, 0.642857142857143, 0.714285714285714, 
3, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Desired output (M):**

```
     Project                       Product     Thing1 Thing2
1  11I040119     Brulerie St. Denis (BOLD) 0.14285714      3
2  11I040119          Ethical Beans (BOLD) 0.24285714      5
3  11I040119                Folgers (BOLD) 0.61428572      0
4  11I040119        Illy drip coffe (BOLD) 0.00000000      0
5  11I040119   Illy Espresso Coffee (BOLD) 0.00000000      0
6  11I040119                Just Us (BOLD) 0.07142857      0
7  11I040119 Lavazza caffè espresso (BOLD) 1.01428571      0
8  11I040119  Lavazza Crema e gusto (BOLD) 0.00000000      0
9  11I040119         Lavazza Tierra (BOLD) 0.97142856      0
10 11I040119         Medaglia d'Oro (BOLD) 0.50000000      0
11 11I040119         Seattle Best 4 (BOLD) 0.35714286      0
12 11I040119  Starbucks café Verona (BOLD) 0.64285714      0
13 11I040119                Tully's (BOLD) 0.71428571      0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a full solution, but for the sake of quickness - The parallelization works by launching multiple processes (imagine running multiple R sessions side-by-side). Each of these processes has its own global environment `.GlobalEnv`, so your `M[r,c] <<- l` is actually assigning somewhere else per process.

One possible implementation would be that you rewrite your function in a way that for example, you return `list(r, c, l)` and use `parLapply` and then you have a list of indices and values collected in parallel and do the assignment in the main process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used `parLapply()` to get the list you mentioned and then simply ran through it with a `sapply()`. Second step was almost instantaneous.

Comment: This is a good example of why one should take a step back and think through ones implementation whenever one end up using `<<-` in the code.  There are very few cases where it is needed.  I suggest that you also rewrite your original `sapply()` so it does not use `<<-`.